# Extract info from address bar in Python

Tags: python, authentication, bottle

I'm new to Python, using Python 3.5.1 (windows)

I'm trying to write a code to automate a login module for an API server

1. The first inputs are an API key and secret which I provide and then I get a URL from the API server and using that we open up the browser pointing to that page which requires us to manually enter the username and password to get authenticated. == so far so good.
2. Once authenticated the server opens up a webpage and displays a token ref in the url parameters, something like

> http://www.xxxx.xx.x.../xxxxxxtoken_ref=a1234xyx

I need to extract the token_ref value and use that for further authentication.

3. I am trying to use a local server at the redirect IP so I can capture the token_ref using Bottle but I think I am doing something wrong.

My code is below:

```
from kiteconnect import KiteConnect
from kiteconnect import websocket
from bottle import run , request , route
import webbrowser
```

## login to kite

```
myapi_key="abcdxyz1234"
myapi_secret = "xxxxyyyyzzzz1234"
kite = KiteConnect(api_key=myapi_key)
url = kite.login_url()
webbrowser.open(url)
```

## get token_request (this is where I'm stuck)

```
@route('/')
def root():
tk_request = request.query.token_request
return 'the token request is' + tk_request
run()
```

## get access token

```
user = kite.request_access_token(request_token=tk_request,secret=api_secret)
```

Comment: what happens when you run your code, and how is that different from what you expect to happen?

Comment: after webbrowser.open(url) the  browser opens with a page that needs an input of username and password and  after the authentication is done the address bar changes to 

https://kite.zerodha.com/dashboard/?status=success&request_token=xxxyyyzz1234xxx
# not sure if i have to start the bottle server before using the webbrowser.open command or after